# SQL Server : could not be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table I want to update this with a view in SQL Server 2008

When I write update sql code like this :

```
UPDATE [dorsadbfitupdetail].[dbo].[tbl_wl_Joint]
SET 
  [JntLineNoInternalUse] = dbo.IpmiLineInternal.LnNo
WHERE     (dbo.tbl_wl_Joint.JntLineNoInternalUse IS NULL)
GO
```

SQL Server throws an error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "dbo.IpmiLineInternal.LnNo" could not be bound.

What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: As Devart says, if you reference `dbo.IpmiLineInternal` then it must be part of your query (ie. present in the FROM clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE j
SET JntLineNoInternalUse = i.LnNo
FROM dbo.tbl_wl_Joint j
JOIN dbo.IpmiLineInternal i ON j.ID = i.ID /* simple change your id columns */
WHERE j.JntLineNoInternalUse IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks but 0 row affected
but in my view dbo.IpmiLineInternal.LnNo h have 2021 record that have LnNo and not have JntLineNoInternalUse !!!